# Joomla 4 - $wa->useScript('...') not working

Tags: joomla, webassets

I am developing a view for the Joomla 4 component. I am trying to connect the style and script files through the WebAssetManager.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->registerScript('com_component.corejs', 'com_component/assets/js/component.js');

if ($wa->assetExists('script', 'com_component.corejs')) {
    var_dump('Script "com_component.corejs" exists!');
}
$wa->useScript('com_component.corejs');

$wa->registerStyle('com_component.corecss', 'com_component/assets/css/component.css', [], ['data-foo' => 'some attribute'], []);
$wa->useStyle('com_component.corecss');
```

The assetExists check is performed, but none of the files are included in the `<head>` of the document.
The json file (/media/com_component/joomla.asset.json) contains an asset with my script.
What could be the problem?

---

Sorry for my English

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Once you create you JSE account, I can assist in migrating this whole page to the CMS-specific site if you like.  With J4 rolling out, it will be great for researchers if all new Joomla content is in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the Joomla4 docks. Files of any assets must be located along the path: `media/com_component/..`
Plus, having looked into the internal components, I corrected the connection. In the end, everything worked :)

```
$ wa = $ this-> document-> getWebAssetManager ();
$ wa-> getRegistry () -> addExtensionRegistryFile ('com_component');

$ wa-> registerStyle ('component_styles', 'com_component / component.css', [], [], []);
$ wa-> useStyle ('component_styles');

$ wa-> registerScript ('component_js', 'com_component / component.js');
$ wa-> useScript ('component_js');
```